# Discord.py - client.send_message() doesn't send message - Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
client = discord.Client()
noticeme = 'notice me senpai'

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    author = message.author
    authorid = message.author.id
    print ("@{} user sent a message. (id: {})".format(author, authorid))

    if message.content == noticeme:
        print ('I noticed you @{}!'.format(authorid))
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'I noticed you @{}!'.format(authorid))
```

I'm trying to make a command that responds with "I noticed you @username!" when you say "notice me senpai" but it doesn't work. (the print DOES work)

Answer (score 1):

```
client = discord.Client()
noticeme = 'notice me senpai'

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    author = message.author
    authorid = message.author.id
    print ("@{} user sent a message. (id: {})".format(author, authorid))

    if message.content == noticeme:
        print ('I noticed you @{}!'.format(authorid))
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'I noticed you @{}!'.format(author))
```

This should be your code.
You used `@bot.event` which should be replaced by `@client.event`.
I tested your code and if you want to use an `@` mention you need to use the `author` variable instead of the `authorid` one.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `await client.send_message()` instead of `await bot.send_message()`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe instead of `await client.send_message(message.channel, 'I noticed you @{}!'.format(author))`, try `await message.send('I noticed you @{}!'.format(author))`

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are using `@bot.event` instead of `@client.event` because you have named your bot variable "client" and not "bot" in the first line of shared code it says:

```py
client = discord.Client()
```

Then in the `on_message` event:

```py
@client.event

async def on_message(message):
    print("{} sent a message.".format(message.author.mention))
    
    if message.content == "notice me senpai":
        print ('I noticed you {}!'.format(message.author.mention))
        await message.channel.send("I have noticed you {}.".format(message.author.mention))
```

As you noticed, I didn't use the "author" variable here because it is not that useful. you can just do: `message.author.mention` instead of assigning a variable a first and then mentioning it.

**Tip:** You can replace 6th line with:

```py
if message.content.lower == "notice me senpai":
```

So that even if user type it in any other way say "nOtIce me senpai" with capital letters in it. It will still send the message.